# Git clone failed with Krb5LoginModule error - JNA Library

Tags: git, java-8, kerberos, jgit

**Insights : -**

I am performing https git clone operation on Azure repository and the request is failing with kerberos auth failure. I am not sure if I am using kerberos internally in my application but this happens only with **Azure** repository clone action.
I tried setting up using "PAT" also but that also didn't help (*Attached stacktrace as well*)

```
**Error -** 
sun.security.jgss.spnego.SpNegoContext.initSecContext(SpNegoContext.java:454)
sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:248)
sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:179)
org.eclipse.jgit.transport.HttpAuthMethod$Negotiate.configureRequest(HttpAuthMethod.java:541)
org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.httpOpen(TransportHttp.java:561)
org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.httpOpen(TransportHttp.java:523)
org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:462)
org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.openFetch(TransportHttp.java:296)
org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:136)
org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:122)
org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1138)
org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:130)
com.xx.git.commands.CloneCommand.fetch(CloneCommand.java:222)
com.xx.git.commands.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:146)
com.xx.git.GitScmService.clone(GitScmService.java:152)
com.xx.git.GitScmService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e66ae5b2.invoke(<generated>)
org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:89)
com.xx.actions.AutoActionTaskAspect.injectScmChangeInfoBuilderAdvice(AutoActionTaskAspect.java:139)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor397.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:634)
org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:624)
org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:72)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
com.xx.git.GitScmService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f03c65a8.clone(<generated>)
com.xx.git.GitConnectionService.cloneRemoteRepository(GitConnectionService.java:336)
com.xx.git.GitConnectionService.cloneAction(GitConnectionService.java:426)
com.xx.git.GitConnectionService.access$200(GitConnectionService.java:84)
com.xx.git.GitConnectionService$1.construct(GitConnectionService.java:224)
com.xx.git.GitConnectionService$1.construct(GitConnectionService.java:211)
com.xx.git.GitConnectionService$2.construct(GitConnectionService.java:234)
com.xx.git.GitConnectionService$2.construct(GitConnectionService.java:231)
com.iconclude.dharma.app.dialogue.TaskProgressDialog$1.doInBackground(TaskProgressDialog.java:373)
javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(SwingWorker.java:295)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(SwingWorker.java:334)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

**Error -**

```
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.promptForPass(Krb5LoginModule.java:925)
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:766)
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Krb5LoginModule.java:618)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:755)
javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195)
javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682)
javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587)
sun.security.jgss.GSSUtil.login(GSSUtil.java:258)
sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Util.getInitialTicket(Krb5Util.java:175)
sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential$1.run(Krb5InitCredential.java:377)
sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential$1.run(Krb5InitCredential.java:373)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getTgt(Krb5InitCredential.java:372)
sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getInstance(Krb5InitCredential.java:160)
sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getCredentialElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:122)
sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getMechanismContext(Krb5MechFactory.java:189)
sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getMechanismContext(GSSManagerImpl.java:224)
sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:212)
sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:179)
sun.security.jgss.spnego.SpNegoContext.GSS_initSecContext(SpNegoContext.java:882)
sun.security.jgss.spnego.SpNegoContext.initSecContext(SpNegoContext.java:317)
sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:248)
sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:179)
org.eclipse.jgit.transport.HttpAuthMethod$Negotiate.configureRequest(HttpAuthMethod.java:541)
org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.httpOpen(TransportHttp.java:561)
org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.httpOpen(TransportHttp.java:523)
org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:462)
org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.openFetch(TransportHttp.java:296)
org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:136)
org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:122)
org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1138)
org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:130)
com.xx.git.commands.CloneCommand.fetch(CloneCommand.java:222)
com.xx.git.commands.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:146)
com.xx.git.GitScmService.clone(GitScmService.java:152)
com.xx.git.GitScmService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e66ae5b2.invoke(<generated>)
org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)\
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:89)
com.xx.actions.AutoActionTaskAspect.injectScmChangeInfoBuilderAdvice(AutoActionTaskAspect.java:139)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor242.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:634)
org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:624)
org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:72)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
com.xx.git.GitScmService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$603f33c2.clone(<generated>)
com.xx.git.GitConnectionService.cloneRemoteRepository(GitConnectionService.java:336)
com.xx.git.GitConnectionService.cloneAction(GitConnectionService.java:426)
com.xx.git.GitConnectionService.access$200(GitConnectionService.java:84)
com.xx.git.GitConnectionService$1.construct(GitConnectionService.java:224)
com.xx.git.GitConnectionService$1.construct(GitConnectionService.java:211)
com.xx.git.GitConnectionService$2.construct(GitConnectionService.java:234)
com.xx.git.GitConnectionService$2.construct(GitConnectionService.java:231)
com.iconclude.dharma.app.dialogue.TaskProgressDialog$1.doInBackground(TaskProgressDialog.java:373)
javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(SwingWorker.java:295)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(SwingWorker.java:334)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

**Followed some remedies :-**

1. Try this steps : - https://groups.google.com/g/gatling/c/4L_OofnOQy0?pli=1
2. Control Panel > Credential Manager
   Check if creds stored in generic password is accurate or not for azure network address.
3. add the IP address of the server in its host file. You must also recycle the application server to load the new host file.
4. Run "Klist" command that comes with java
   Check for server by name kerberos (like Server: krbtgt...)
5. https://support.tibco.com/s/article/Spotfire-Server-KERBEROS-ERROR-No-valid-credentials-provided-Mechanism-level-No-valid-credentials-provided-Mechanism-level-Connection-timed-out-connect

**Versions :-**
I am using jdk 8 version.
Our dekstop application uses Git 2.39.2.windows.1 version to perform clone.
org.eclipse.jgit.ssh.jsch-5.13.1.202206130422-r.jar

org.eclipse.jgit.ui-5.13.1.202206130422-r.jar

org.eclipse.jgit-5.13.1.202206130422-r.jar